# MySql trigger Syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

Could someone please tell me what's wrong with my Mysql-syntax in the following trigger?

```
 CREATE TRIGGER hQual AFTER INSERT ON Musikstück FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
IF(length(NEW.bitrate)=4) THEN 
    IF ((CONVERT(substr(NEW.bitrate,2,3),SIGNED INTEGER))<320) THEN
        UPDATE Album SET High_Quality = 0 WHERE Album.Albumname=NEW.Albumname; 
    END IF 
ELSEIF((CONVERT(NEW.bitrate,SIGNED INTEGER))<320) THEN 
    UPDATE Album SET High_Quality = 0 WHERE Album.Albumname=NEW.Albumname;
END IF 
END
```

It's too late over here, I'm tired and I don't see it :) MySql is just saying:

*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4*

Comment: Do you have a delimiter statement before (and after) the trigger definition?

Comment: No, do i have to? I'm just putting it the way I posted it into the phpmyadmin "SQL" tab.

Comment: Ok after more google I that i have to use Delimiter // in front of the trigger, thank you!